# validation Rule - OR

Tags: validation-rule

I am working on a validation rule where I does not want a field (Web Form) to be equal to the below mentioned 2 email IDs. It's giving me a syntax error. Can anyone please suggest on the below please :

```
OR(
Web_Form_Source__c <> "goldrush.oliverhume.com.au", "builders.oliverhume.com.au"),
GSR_Referral_Date_Time__c == null
)
```

Comment: YEs, it's a validation rule basically the requiment is eaither of these URLs should be in the address field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) The OR should be an AND. When using `<>` (not equals), if it's equal to one value, it will not be equal to the other-- therefore it will always return true, so it would always be wrong.

(b) The validation rule should return true when it **should** error, not when it should pass.

(c) You have to compare against a field every time, so you can't just use a simple comma (`,`).

(d) You can use CASE to reduce field references.

So, you might write your formula as this:

```
CASE(
    Web_Form_Source__c, 
    "goldrush.oliverhume.com.au", 1,
    "builders.oliverhume.com.au", 1,
    0) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Web_Form_Source__c = "goldrush.oliverhume.com.au" || Web_Form_Source__c = "builders.oliverhume.com.au"
```

If it's a validation rule and you don't want to allow these 2 email addresses, then the validation rule needs to evaluate to true.